# How to prevent fixtures to update the DB in Django?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, python-2.7, django-models

I'm deploying a Django application as a deb file. The user is installing it using dpkg. When there is an update the user is installing it using dpkg and the application is updated.

In every install process the is user is loading the default data from fixtures automatically.

Consider s/he changed the default admin password. When s/he updates the deb package the password is set to default.

I have tried to check if there is an old version already intalled in the system. So I can pass over *loaddata* issues.

However the solution I provided above is not a good solution. Does Django provides a mechanism or choice for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this problem by editing the installation script.

If it's not the installation or in other words the user is updating the *loaddata* is not run.

I think the only solution is this instead of using migration.